# IE- Hide dropdown/add or remove using Jquery? How can I achieve the same result in IE like firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, show-hide

I need to achieve the following scenario.I did and it works in firefox.But not in IE.

**Sceario:**

1. If I select the value from first dropdown the remaining dropdowns must hide that options.
2. If I deselect the option from first dropdown it should available for remaining dropdowns.
3. It goes on untill the last dropdown.

I have the following code

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select data-label="Question 1" class="u85" id="test1">
        <option value="Please select...">Please select...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select data-label="Question 1" class="u85" id="test2">
            <option value="Please select...">Please select...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select data-label="Question 1" class="u85" id="test3">
            <option value="Please select...">Please select...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select data-label="Question 1" class="u85" id="test4">
            <option value="Please select...">Please select...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Then I have the follwoing Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var selectionlist=[];
        $('select').change(function() 
        {   
            var currentid=$(this).attr("id");
            $(this).val()!=="Please select..."?selectionlist[$(this).parent().index()]=$(this).val():selectionlist[$(this).parent().index()]="";
            $('select').each(function(i){
            var currentselectboxid=$(this).attr("id");
                if($(this).val()!=="Please select...")
                    selectionlist[i]=$(this).val();

                    $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+' option').each(function(){

                            $.inArray($(this).val(),selectionlist)!=-1?$(this).hide():$(this).show();
                    });
            });

        });
    });
```

This works fine in Firefox.But not in IE.I already found something in google.

[JQuery Hide Option doesn't work in IE and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373735/jquery-hide-option-doesnt-work-in-ie-and-safari)

If I disable it , it works fine.But My requirement is hide and show. I try to add and remove the options. But not geeting success.

How can I achieve the same result like firefox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on where you are getting your options from, but I would hold the set in a collection. Each one would have a property called "selected" and set to "false" upon start. Then, I would build each of the dropdowns using this collection, and only create the option if the item's selected value is set to false. When a dropdown changes, set the "selected" value for the corresponding item to "true" and rebuild the remaining dropdowns. That way you don't have to deal with hiding/showing or disabling an option.

Comment: My requirement is fully hide the option from the dropdown.Even the user selects the dropdown it wont be shown in the second.

Comment: yep, and if you only build the remaining dropdowns from the items in the collection that have their value set to false...you'd have that.

Answer (score 0):

This might help...

I've made a jQuery Plugin that should help you.  With it, you would do this:

```
$('#selection1').hideOption('1');
$('#selection1').showOption('1');
```

You can hide and show them as much as you want - they keep their original order. It works in all browsers. You can see that in this sample: [jsFiddle - Toggle Dropdown Options](http://jsfiddle.net/glittle/RvGTc/)

You can get the [Toggle Dropdown Options plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/sunwapta.toggleOption/). If you don't like plug-ins, just copy the JavaScript code from it to your own project's JavaScript file. See the [Read the Docs](https://github.com/glittle/sunwapta.jquery.toggleOption) link on the plug-in for more information!