# How to hide drop down options in I.E

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I'm trying to create a jquery, that will filter the choises of a dropdown menu in IE. I tried following the instructions from [JQuery Hide Option doesn't work in IE and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373735/jquery-hide-option-doesnt-work-in-ie-and-safari) (user kinnou), but it seems like hiding is also deleting options.
The code is:

```
function filterDP(element) {
    var value = $(element).val();
    var dropdown = "#dropdownIdName";

    $( dropdown+" > option").each(function() {
        var optionValue = $(this).val();
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            $(dropdown).find('option[value="' + optionValue + '"]').map(function () {return $(this).parent('span').length === 0 ? this : null;})
                .wrap('<span>');
        } //'Microsoft Internet Explorer'           
        if ((value == "") ||  ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) ){ // Found=>show();
            if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
                $(dropdown).find('option[value="'+optionValue+'"]').unwrap().show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).show(); //all other browsers use standard .show();                      
            }
        }               
        else { // not found=> Hide
            $(dropdown).find('option[value="'+optionValue+'"]').hide();
        }
        else { 
            $(this).hide(); //all other browsers use standard .show();                      
        }
    });
}
```

And the code to activate it:

```
aa.prepend($('<input/>', {id: 'DPFilter',
                          onkeyup: 'filterDP(this)'
                         }));
```

Comment: You'll have to redraw the <select> tag and all its <option> tags everytime you're appending a new filter.

Comment: Your brackets aren't properly balanced in the `filterDP` function.

Comment: I've corrected them  @Barmar.

Comment: Looks like you're using `.map()` in a way that should be `.filter()`.

Comment: There's nothing in there that deletes anything from the DOM. All it does is wrap and unwrap a span around the options. Have you looked in the DOM inspector to see whether things are being deleted?

Comment: At the console, i try $( dropdown+" > option"). First is 9 items. If i add characters  it gets 5-4-2, if i remove the characters, it stays at the same number and never gets 9 again. I'm trying to impelement the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373735/jquery-hide-option-doesnt-work-in-ie-and-safari

Comment: I guess you are right: $(dropdown).find('option[value="' + 9 + '"]').html() return values. so, where are the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in line: 
     $( dropdown+" > option").each(function(). 
Everytime an input was made, a "option" was wrapped with "span". So, the $( dropdown+" > option"), returned fewer and fewer options.
The line should change to : 
     $( dropdown).find("option").each(function() ...