# removing all elements from a select

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide all items in a select box onload, but the items seem to still appear. This has been run in other functions and seems to work perfect. Can someone take a look at it, thanks.

```
$('#Building_Name').load(function () {
    $('#Building_Name').children('option').hide();

});
```

Comment: `load` is not an event that is triggered on `select` elements. So the function is never called. What did you intend with this?

Comment: Thanks felix, when the page load I would like to remove all elements from the select.

Comment: Would you like to remove or hide; the two are not the same? @jpavlov?

Comment: IE doesn't support hiding option tag  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373735/jquery-hide-option-doesnt-work-in-ie-and-safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really want to hide options there is no way for IE. If you want to disable options, then you can for IE too :-)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Building_Name option").prop("disabled",true);
})
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ydeLhq/3/) is jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Thanks. the IE thing is killing me, looks like I am going to have to set it up another way.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use css to hide these items ?

```
select option {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to remove them you can use this code:

```
$('#Building_Name>option').remove();
```