# Select box option hide display in IE browser

Tags: jquery, html

I have implemented jquery to remove duplicate select option from multiple select box if it is already selected. This works fine in Firefox and chrome. But when I try the same in IE it fails. Duplicate questions are not removed/hide from the list.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change', function(event) {
    //restore previously selected value
    var prevValue = $(this).data('previous');
    $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + prevValue + '"]').show();

    //hide option selected now
    var value = $(this).val();
    //update previously selected data
    $(this).data('previous', value);
    $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
});
});
</script>

<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<table>
<th>
QNA multiple select box
</th>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="selectBox1" id="selectBox1" class="wgtmsr">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
    <option value="option5">option5</option>
    <option value="option6">option6</option>
    <option value="option7">option7</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="select1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="selectBox2" id="selectBox2" class="wgtmsr">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
    <option value="option5">option5</option>
    <option value="option6">option6</option>
    <option value="option7">option7</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="select2">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="selectBox3" id="selectBox3" class="wgtmsr">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
    <option value="option5">option5</option>
    <option value="option6">option6</option>
    <option value="option7">option7</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="select3">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="selectBox4" id="selectBox4" class="wgtmsr">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
    <option value="option5">option5</option>
    <option value="option6">option6</option>
    <option value="option7">option7</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="select4">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i missing to achieve the same functionality in IE.

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/junaidaj86/qs0e3hLz/)

Comment: Creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will increase chances to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Created one for reference. You can see the link in my question.

Answer (score 1):

.show() and hide() doesn't work for select options in ie. You can try several workarounds stated in this answer : [JQuery Hide Option doesn't work in IE and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373735/jquery-hide-option-doesnt-work-in-ie-and-safari)

One of them would be the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/4bvw91pm/

```
$.fn.showOption = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        if( this.tagName == "OPTION" ) {
            var opt = this;
            if( $(this).parent().get(0).tagName == "SPAN" ) {
                var span = $(this).parent().get(0);
                $(span).replaceWith(opt);
                $(span).remove();
            }
            opt.disabled = false;
            $(opt).show();
        }
    });
    return this;
    }
    $.fn.hideOption = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        if( this.tagName == "OPTION" ) {
            var opt = this;
            if( $(this).parent().get(0).tagName == "SPAN" ) {
                var span = $(this).parent().get(0);
                $(span).hide();
            } else {
                $(opt).wrap("span").hide();
            }
            opt.disabled = true;
        }
    });
    return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Easiest fix for this problem would be :

**Replace this line:**

```
$('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
```

**With this line :**

```
$('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').prop('disabled','disabled');
```

AND

**Remove this line:**

```
$('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + prevValue + '"]').show();
```

**Add this line instead :**

```
$('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + prevValue + '"]').prop('disabled',false);
```